# Method name gets changed in storyboard connections inspector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, swift2

I created a method for a button using `Swift 2.3` in `Xcode 8`. let's say

```
 @IBAction func testAction(sender: UIButton) {
     print("\(sender.tag)");
 }
```

but in `Connections inspector` of storyboard editor it shows as `testActionWithSender:`, which I know is not the correct method name but I have no problem with that until it crashes with

> [TestProject.ViewController testActionWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff3f3e050e0

on button tap.

So why does the method name changes in `Connections inspector` and how do I fix it?

Comment: Usually this happens when you mad a connection, and then changed it, so it saving and referring to the old one also, how to fix: go to the connection inspector and delete the " testActionWith.." And make sure only the "testAction" is connected for the button.

Comment: oh God, I thought how could I make mad a connection. does connection has feelings? :D . Joking aside, yes I tried fresh method. didn't changed it. Xcode just appends parameter with method name in connections inspector. don't know why. you can try in `Xcode8`.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By Using this workaround you can add existing action and also can connect multiple buttons to a single action.**

I think there is a bug in Xcode8. You can add multiple/Single button to a single action /function by changing `sender` to `_ sender`

eg :- Normal Button

```
   @IBAction func huu(sender: UIButton) {

   }
```

You can't add multiple buttons or single button to this action you need to simply change like this and then you can add multiple buttons by using drag and connect from storyboard.

```
 @IBAction func huu(_ sender: UIButton) {

 }
```

After connecting IBOutlets Xcode will show a warning like this :-

[image]

To remove this warning simple delete `_` sign from the action/function. Make sure that to delete `_` after connecting your IBOutlets

Hope that this will gonna help you! :)

Comment: Well, `(_ sender: UIButton)` does solve the many-to-one method connection issue.

Comment: So is this solution to your question ?

Comment: :) half of it. I still need solution to resolve drag and create action which shows correct in `Connections inspector`. Anyway, accepting your answer.

Comment: Same here, still searching for a better one. I think  it's an xcode 8 bug :)

Comment: Thanks, for the solutions. Really annoying problem or a bug maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The only workaround I found is to delete the connection, and drag the button action to a new Action method.

If you link your button to an existing one, it crashes

Comment: But if I drag a button action it shows missing connection, though it works. Problem is you cannot connect single method to multiple buttons.